# Switch from Workgroup to Domain in cmd

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-domain, workgroup

I was experimenting on file sharing in Windows and changed corporate domain on a workgroup.

Now when I log in, I see only other accounts, possibly created earlier in that particular workgroup. So, now I stuck on a lock screen. The only thing I can probably do is by holding shift restart the computer and enter the cmd.

I found netdom & net commands in the Net, but the former doesn't work in the shell. I'd be glad to receive any help.

Comment: If you removed it from the domain it needs to be added again? I'm not familiar with corporate environment but shouldn't it be in Settings > System > About then click Join a domain?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia As I said I checked checkbox, something like "Use Workgroup instead of Domain". After that I restarted the computer and since then cannot login to the system, because there are no accounts available which I can access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't join a Domain without

- being able to see it on the network
- having access to a domain administrator account
- having access to a local administrator account

When you left your corporate domain, you obviously created the need to again join it, so you need all three of the above. Your corporate IT department can help you, but it would be an enormous implementation error, if you could do it without them.

Comment: I think an enormous **security** error as well; unless the person is already part of domain admins and local admins.